# Sorting a list of strings of letters and numbers based on variable length number at multiple levels in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I am attempting to find a way to sort a list of strings in Python.  The challenge I'm facing is that I want to sort them only based on the numbers in the first line of each string which themselves are separated into multiple levels.

An example of a list would look like this:

```
interfaces_list = [
    'int Eth4/3/2\n more stuff',
    'int Eth3/33\n more stuff',
    'int Eth1/48\n more stuff',
    'int Eth4/21/1\n more stuff',
    'int Eth5/7\n more stuff',
    'int Eth4/3/1\n more stuff'
]
```

For the sorting, I'd like to ignore the 'int Eth' prefix for each string and sort only based on the numbers.  This also needs to be done for each level.  So sorting based on the first number, then the second number, then (if present), the third number.

In the end, I would like to end up with this:

```
interfaces_list_sorted = [
    'int Eth1/48\n more stuff',
    'int Eth3/33\n more stuff',
    'int Eth4/3/1\n more stuff',
    'int Eth4/3/2\n more stuff',
    'int Eth4/21/1\n more stuff',
    'int Eth5/7\n more stuff'
]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you safely assume `'more stuff'` doesn't have numbers/digits in it?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  'more stuff' could also contain numbers that specifically should NOT be sorted on.

Comment: `sorted(interfaces_list, key=lambda x: [int(x) for x in re.findall('\d+', x.split('\n')[0])])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` in the sort key:

```
import re
interfaces_list = [
'int Eth4/3/2\n more stuff',
'int Eth3/33\n more stuff',
'int Eth1/48\n more stuff',
'int Eth4/21/1\n more stuff',
'int Eth5/7\n more stuff',
'int Eth4/3/1\n more stuff'
]
final_data = sorted(interfaces_list, key=lambda x:list(map(int, re.findall('[0-9/]+(?=\n\smore)', x)[0].split('/'))))
```

`re.findall` with `'\d+'` will attempt to grab all the instances of a "run" of digits in the string. However, since the returned type is a list of strings, each string in the list has to be cast as an integer for proper comparison by the sort algorithm. `map` applies the `int` function to every element in the list.

Output:

```
['int Eth1/48\n more stuff', 
'int Eth3/33\n more stuff', 
'int Eth4/3/1\n more stuff', 
'int Eth4/3/2\n more stuff', 
'int Eth4/21/1\n more stuff', 
'int Eth5/7\n more stuff']
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked perfectly for Python 2.  However, I'm attempting to do what I can in Python 3 and it doesn't seem to be working there.  Sorry, I'm still a beginner!

Comment: @Dime-a-tron glad to help! Please see my recent edit. The solution will now work for both Python versions.

Comment: Incredible!  What the heck did people do before the Internet.  Again, thank you so much.  I will now spend the next few hours reverse engineering this to make sure I understand the pieces.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Dime-a-tron Please see my recent edit. I added an explanation for the solution.

Comment: Again, thank you.  That helps to clarify.  Is there a way to check for only the first run of digits?  In some of my testing of this, the '\n more stuff' can contain additional runs of numbers that I do not want to sort on.  I only want to sort on the contents of the first line of each list item.

Comment: @Dime-a-tron please see my recent edit. I added a regex lookahead and an additional split.

Comment: You are a saint!  Thanks for all your help tonight.

Comment: @Dime-a-tron glad to help!